# How do I get the contents of a Tk listbox without selecting each item?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a Tk listbox widget (chosenItems) that gets populated with selected items from another listbox (possibleItems). When a user has chosen all the items they want to manipulate or change, I have a button (Apply) that applies a set of transformations to the list of "chosenItems". To make this work, I need to collect all the entries of the Tk listbox.

How do I do that and generate a list for those items?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, not tested: you can specify a `-listvariable`, which will hold all items in the list, or use the `get` subcommand, e.g. `$myListbox get 0 end`.

Answer (score 0):

The Tk listbox supports a `get` command, so something like:

```
set lbentries [.l get 0 end]
```

should give you a list of all the entries in the list box (where `.l` is the listbox widget command).

Alternately, you could use the `-listvariable` option to the widget and manage the contents of the list box via a global variable.

Take another close read of the listbox manual page and you'll see the options available to you.

Comment: Manual page? Are there man pages for TCL/Tk widgets? Or is this in a book? I'm currently using Brent Welch's "Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk", but it seems really out of date.

Comment: You're missing out: https://tcl.tk/man/ -- you'll definitely want to bookmark the docs for your version.

Comment: Tcl is well documented and the official documentation is kept up to date. Invariably, books fall behind despite how helpful they may be in getting you started. Also the Tcl wiki is a wealth of information.